# Sui verbi, con esempi, "talentare" e "attalentare"

Tags: grammar, verbs, phrase-request

Ero quasi pronto a postare una questione su german.stackexchange su due ipotetici verbi, uno dei quali pensavo non esistesse in italiano e non sono sicuro se il verbo a cui farò riferimento sarà quello o meno, quando inciampo in due verbi strani nel senso di "mai incontrati" nell’italiano dalle mie parti (sicuramente, anche se non ricordo, in latino o letteratura l’avrò incontrato; diversamente non so spiegarmi, al di là dell’automatismo, come mi si sia formato in mente questo verbo).

Veniamo al dunque: noi tutti – o almeno io – abbiamo usato almeno una volta l’aggettivo "[talentuoso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/talentuoso/)", derivato dalla parola "talento" (solo oggi scopro che esiste anche "[talentoso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/talentoso/)" anche se per quanto mi riguarda non lo intendo nel *sign. 2* del Treccani, ovvero "... pieno di talento, d’ingegno ...").

Nel postare dai [cugini latini](https://german.stackexchange.com/) mi posi una domanda ovverosia "esiste un verbo che indica specificatamente una qualche relazione con "talentuoso" (in tedesco sarebbe "talentiert")?" Pensai subito di no, poi pensandoci ancora bene e spremendo le meningi e pensando all’italiano mi uscì naturale il verbo "talentare" e googlando [**lo**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/talentare/) trovai, vi linko Treccani ma sappiate che ho controllato tutti i dizionari online (quindi "Please, non cerco un riferimento per il significato del verbo"), trovando anche e inoltre "[attalentare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/attalentare/)". I due sono verbi *bellissimi*, scusate il mio stupore fanciullesco nell’aggettivo, peccato che gli esempi sembrano un po lontani dall´odierno italiano eppure si capiscono facilmente sostituendo adeguatamente le forme [..]andare a genio/talento[..], [..]garbare[..], [..]piacere[..]. Non capisco però se esiste quel nesso che cerco con l’aggettivo, direi di no o mi sfugge qualcosa nel senso forse non tanto del verbo quanto della parola "talento"?!. Ovvero, i due verbi sono connessi all’aggettivo? O meglio senza troppe "seghe mentali" cercando di capirli piú nell’uso, come posso, diciamo, verbalizzare, usando uno dei due verbi, le seguenti frasi?

> è talentuoso
>
> egli mostra/ha talento in quello che fa

Usando semplicemente "(at)talenta" come segue rispettivamente?

> (at)talenta
>
> (at)talenta in quello che fa

Teoricamente direi che le due frasi sono possibili grammaticalmente in italiano, ma la questione ancora una volta è la seguente "il loro senso/significato è quello rispettivo della frase nominalizzata o no? Se avete esempi di frasi, possibilmente con fonti (anche da cercare fuori dal WWW), ringrazio a priori se le citate (possibilmente non già trovate nei dizionari online da me già controllati)

E ancora, i verbi "attalentare" e "talentare" si relazionano tra loro proprio come "attecchire" e "[tecchire](http://www.etimo.it/?term=tecchire)", "attediare" e "tediare", "attentare" e "tentare", "attemperare" e "temperare", "attanagliare" e "tanagliare".. ho intuito correttamente? Se si, non esiste nessuna sfumatura di significato tra i due verbi, mi riferisco ad "attalentare" e "talentare"? A me suona il verbo con la particella "*a*" di un senso più marcato, grave, rispetto a quello senza (anche se non so in che modo non avendo esempi), per spiegarmi mi viene in mente l’analogia con i verbi tedeschi, ad esempio "folgen" e "verfolgen" i quali sarrebbero "seguire" ed "inseguire" e il verbo con il prefisso "*ver*" indica un´azione più intensa (quasi negativa anche se non sempre) rispetto a quello senza. Perdonatemi la mia continua analogia col tedesco...)

E ancora, dai verbi "attalentare" e "talentare" posso formare dei participi del tipo "attalentante" o "talentante"? Teoricamente anche qui direi di si ma non sono sicuro e a corto sono anche di esempi per cogliere un attimino il senso d’uso di questi due, ergo sarei grato a chi voglia postarne alcuni (con e senza fonti purché corretti!). Sarei interessato anche ad esempi con i participi "talentato" e "attalentato"

PS=Mi interessano anche esempi, e ripeto "non presi dai dizionari online", con i due verbi messi a titolo, se possibile da libri.

(Mi scuso a priori con @DaG qualora il post ha accenti fuori o mal posti)

*UPDATE 01:18 - 03-05-2017*: dopo un po’ di commenti con @DaG e @Denis Nardin, e letture consigliate, eliminerei il nesso che cerco tra la frase "è talentuoso" con i verbi, mi hanno convinto, tuttavia rimane ancora il dubbio con la frase "mostrare/avere talento in qualcosa" (in qualche sfumatura di significato, del tipo "gli piace/aggrada/va a genio quella cosa" per dire "è predisposto/talentuoso"...). Ne approfitto per ringraziare i due utenti, vuoi vedere che risolviamo, a via di limature di significati, la questione senza una risposta, e mi sembrava complessa LOL!!

Comment: Grazie per le scuse: ti confermo che gli accenti sono un po' a vanvera. :-)

Comment: Comunque, non sono sicuro di aver capito bene la domanda. Ti è chiaro che talentare e attalentare *non* significano "mostrare/avere talento"?

Comment: si e no, la treccani scrive "andare a genio", oltre a "piacere" e "garbare" .., e non so perché in certi contesti mi suona "talentare" inteso come "andare a genio" come "mostrare/avere talento" ergo "essere talentuoso" nel senso di "attitudine/predisposizione avere" (ovvero talento possedere, in questo o altro cosa). Scusa se ti parlo con frasi e cerco di spiegarmi tramite queste ma non riesco diversamente..

Comment: Hai dato un'occhiata a Google Google? Per esempio: https://books.google.it/books?id=6HdCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA278&dq="attalentare"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_uMa2ntLTAhWMOsAKHT5YCDkQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22attalentare%22&f=false, https://books.google.it/books?id=FyU0AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA319&dq="talentare"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidkL7HndLTAhVhCcAKHducAEgQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22talentare%22&f=false, https://books.google.it/books?id=JU6YwV6otkYC&pg=PT195&dq="attalentare"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic_q7CntLTAhUiIMAKHa1PDBM4ChDoAQg9MAc#v=onepage&q=%22attalentare%22&f=false etc?

Comment: Ma "andare a genio" non significa mica "mostrare talento"...

Comment: ja, das ist wahr,,, nemmeno nel senso di "essere gradita"? Mi spiego, mi viene spontaneo usare quando vedo persone ferrate nel loro mestiere, ergo predisposte, perché no "talentuose" (esempio, colleghi di informatica, o amici musicisti), dire "e certo, la cosa ti va a genio!" nel senso di "fatta per te, ti é gradita ergo", quell´uso di "andare a genio" non per forza in senso negativo...

Comment: forse mi illudo di cercare quella dannata sfumatura che mi permetta di cogliere il nesso con l´aggettivo o parola "talentuoso" o "talento" (guarda caso scopro proprio ora su googgle books che esiste anche in tedesco "talentieren" e in testi che avrrei paura a postare sul futuro post)...@DaG, critica tranquillamente se devio coi sensi delle parole e forse troppo esageratamente..

Comment: @mle Sono un po' confuso: *mostrare talento* ed *essere gradito* sono due lemmi completamente diversi.. Forse li confondi?

Comment: @DenisNardin, Non proprio, non ti posso rispondere sicuro, spero lo capirai! "essere gradito" come "andare a genio" (in senso positivo, non penso che "(at)talentare" sia "non andare a genio"). Su "Mostrare talento" non saprei, e in merito chiedo nel post originale, tuttavia (in senso positivo) "gli va a genio quello che fa" (o "gli (at)talenta quello che fa") per dire "mostra talento in quello che fa" mi suona ok, non riesco a capire il perché invece mi suona ok. Non sembra anche a voi che in certi contesti é possibile?

Comment: @mle Onestamente, no. *Mi va a genio* e *mi è gradito* sono essenzialmente indistinguibili ai miei orecchi, mentre *mostrare talento* mi sembra completamente distinto da entrambi (posso avere talento in qualcosa e odiare farla, posso amar fare una cosa ed essere una frana). Sentiamo se qualcuno ha un'opinione diversa.

Comment: quindi é come dire nel tuo esempio, "non mi talenta laddove ho/mostro talento"... nel senso di "non mi va a genio/non mi é gradito ció in cui ho talento", corretto? Se si, non é un nonsense? Tuttavia curioso esempio...

Comment: @mle Si tratta di verbi arcaici, e non più compresi dall'italiano medio credo (almeno io non li conoscevo), ma sì è una frase curiosa.

Comment: @DaG, ho letto la frase dal  "Raggionamenti sopra le Litanie di nostra Signora, Volume 1 By Niccolò Riccardi", e mi sfugge un attimo il senso di quel "attalentare" (da minuti che leggo la frase, qui https://books.google.de/books?id=uxyoke_qJ6kC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=attalentare+i+cuori+di+se+medesimo&source=bl&ots=xu-OXeULWw&sig=2WAbqC1DAmtJ58P_b25rTtgKKNc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ-ZKQqdLTAhWF6RQKHfSBA4sQ6AEILTAA#v=onepage&q=attalentare%20i%20cuori%20di%20se%20medesimo&f=false meglio), mentre per gli altri testi, per i quali ti ringrazio di averli linkati, é chiaro il verbo e "non ci piove"...

Comment: @mle Ultimo commento, ma in quel passaggio *attalentare i cuori di sè medesimo* significa *far desiderare sè medesimo dai cuori* (cfr. l'esempio di Poliziano nel vocabolario Treccani)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58092/discussion-between-mle-and-denis-nardin).